# Closing JFrame on Mouse Click

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Hey guys, I want my JFrame to close on a mouse click. I have code to do it, but it isn't working...

```
public void closeFrame ()
{

    jPanel.removeAll ();
    String x = "";
    JLabel exit = new JLabel ("Click Anywhere To Close!", JLabel.CENTER);
    exit.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (700, 100));
    jPanel.add (exit);
    jPanel.revalidate ();

    MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter ()
    {
        public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent event)
        {
            //Put JFrame close code here
            dispose ();
            System.exit (0);
        }
    }
    ;
    addMouseListener (ml);
    validate (); //This hasn't made a difference :(

}
```

The class extends JFrame and it DOESNT implement MouseListener. Nonetheless, the code doesn't work.

This is what the initialization of the JFrame looks like (hope it helps)...

```
public void createFrame ()
{
    new JFrame (":) :)");
    setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible (true);
    //Some Initialization for jPanel variable
    getContentPane().add(jPanel);
    pack();
}
```

How can I make this code work & if I can't, is there an alternate way of closing on mouse click?

---EDIT---

Thanks goes to Hovercraft Full Of Eels

The MouseListener must be added to the JPanel

```
//WORKING CODE
public void closeFrame ()
{

    jPanel.removeAll ();
    String x = "";
    JLabel exit = new JLabel ("Click Anywhere To Close!", JLabel.CENTER);
    exit.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (700, 100));
    jPanel.add (exit);
    //jPanel.revalidate ();

    MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter ()
    {
        public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent event)
        {
            //Put JFrame close code here
            dispose ();
            System.exit (0);
        }
    }
    ;
    jPanel.addMouseListener (ml);
    jPanel.revalidate ();

}
```

Comment: "I want my JFrame to close on a mouse click."  You mean if the frame is partially obscured by other windows, and I see part of it and click it to bring it to front, you want it should close instead?  *Why?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to wonder if the JFrame contentPane that you've added the MouseListener to is not the same as the JFrame that's being displayed, especially since I see you creating a new JFrame in your createFrame method. You understand that the MouseListener will only work if added to a visualized component, right?

Suggestions:

- don't have your class extend JFrame
- Add your MouseListener to the JPanel that you're adding to the visualized JFrame's contentPane.
- Give your class a JFrame variable and have it refer to the JFrame that you're creating in the createFrame method.  Then you may dispose of this JFrame as you see fit.
- Don't forget to call the setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) on the visualized JFrame.

Comment: Omg HFOE, you did it. All I needed to do was add the mouseListener to the Panel instead of the frame (STUPID ME!!) - Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did.

```
btnClose = new JButton("Close");
btnClose.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        dispose();
    }
});
btnClose.setBounds(253, 190, 75, 25);
contentPane.add(btnClose);
}
```